# mongodb aggregation: if value of two fields match, add corresponding dictionary's another filed's value to a new field

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following result after using aggregation lookup among three collections.

```
[{
_id : "henten",
location: "some place",
devices: [
    {"d_id": 'd0001',
     "z_id": 'z2001'},
    {"d_id": 'd0002',
     "z_id": 'z2002'}
],
store: [
    {"z_name" : 'vera',
     "z_id" : 'z2001'},
    {"z_name" : 'ghora',
     "z_id" : 'z2002'}
]
}]
```

I need to push the value of 'd_id' to the dictionaries of 'store' as an array to a new field named 'DID', if devices.z_id matches with store.z_id.

I have tried the following:

```
{
        $addFields: {
            "store.DID" :
            {$filter: {
                input: "$devices.d_id",
                as: 'did',
                cond: {$eq: ['$devices.z_id', '$store.z_id']}
                }}
}}
```

I have also tried $redact and $arrayElemAt which gives me same wrong results as follows:

```
[{
_id : "henten",
location: "some place",
devices: [
    {"d_id": 'd0001',
     "z_id": 'z2001'},
    {"d_id": 'd0002',
     "z_id": 'z2002'}
],
store: [
    {"z_name" : 'vera',
     "z_id" : 'z2001',
     "DID" : ['d0001', 'd0002']},
    {"z_name" : 'ghora',
     "z_id" : 'z2002',
     "DID" : ['d0001', 'd0002']}
]
}]
```

Whereas the correct answer should be:

```
[{
_id : "henten",
location: "some place",
devices: [
    {"d_id": 'd0001',
     "z_id": 'z2001'},
    {"d_id": 'd0002',
     "z_id": 'z2002'}
],
store: [
    {"z_name" : 'vera',
     "z_id" : 'z2001',
     "DID" : ['d0001']},
    {"z_name" : 'ghora',
     "z_id" : 'z2002',
     "DID" : ['d0002']}
]
}]
```

How should i approach this? One z_id could have two different d_id and thus should have those two d_id inside the DID array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can to run a combination of [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) and [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html), try:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            store: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$store",
                    as: "s",
                    in: {
                        z_name: "$$s.z_name",
                        z_id: "$$s.z_id",
                        DID: {
                            $map: {
                                input: { 
                                    $filter: {
                                        input: "$devices",
                                        as: "d",
                                        cond: { $eq: [ "$$d.z_id", "$$s.z_id" ] }
                                    }
                                },
                                as: "filtered",
                                in: "$$filtered.d_id"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nRo-NRqaKGX)